# Hadoop in LXC container error : YARN : 1/1 local-dirs are bad

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, lxc

I have two hadoop instances running inside two lxc containers on the same host, a hadoop-master and a hadoop-slave1.
While starting YARN & DFS on master I get this UNHEALTHY state for hadoop-slave1.

For what I've found on the web it must be one of these two possibilities:

- Not enough disk space.
- Permission issue

a. `df -h` says otherwise :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        91G   68G   19G  79% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,8G  4,0K  3,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           769M  1,3M  768M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,8G  536K  3,8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
```

b.
 `ll /usr/local/hadoop` :

```
............
drwxr-xr-x  2 hduser hadoop  4096 Mar  8 19:10 local/
```

`ll /usr/local/hadoop/logs` :

```
total 132
drwxr-xr-x  3 hduser hadoop  4096 Mar  8 18:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 hduser hadoop  4096 Mar  8 18:54 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser hadoop 46222 Mar  8 18:55 hadoop-hduser-datanode-hadoop-slave1.log
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser hadoop   718 Mar  8 18:55 hadoop-hduser-datanode-hadoop-slave1.out
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser hadoop     0 Mar  8 17:08 SecurityAuth-hduser.audit
drwxr-xr-x  2 hduser hadoop  4096 Mar  8 19:10 userlogs/
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser hadoop 56645 Mar  8 19:08 yarn-hduser-nodemanager-hadoop-slave1.log
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser hadoop   702 Mar  8 18:56 yarn-hduser-nodemanager-hadoop-slave1.out
```

my yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
                <value>hadoop-master:8025</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
                <value>hadoop-master:8030</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
                <value>hadoop-master:8050</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
                <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/local</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

And the error that ResourceManager complains about:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: Node hadoop-slave1:48673 reported UNHEALTHY with details: 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/local; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs
```

They say [here](http://gethue.com/hadoop-yarn-11-local-dirs-are-bad-varlibhadoop-yarncacheyarnnm-local-dir-11-log-dirs-are-bad-varloghadoop-yarncontainers/) that I need to make some disk space, isn't there the same disk space for the lxc-container as there is for the host OS ?
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Edit:

I have completely overlooked this in the NodeManager error log:

```
2015-03-10 08:15:17,671 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection: Directory /usr/local/hadoop/local error, Directory is not executable: /usr
/local/hadoop/local, removing from list of valid directories
2015-03-10 08:15:17,671 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection: Directory /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs error, Directory is not executab
le: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs, removing from list of valid directories
2015-03-10 08:15:17,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService: Disk(s) failed: 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/local; 1/1 l
og-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs
2015-03-10 08:15:17,671 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService: Most of the disks failed. 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/l
ocal; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs
```

Comment: but is `/usr/local/hadoop/local` available *for the slave1 lxc container* ?

Comment: You may also consider YARN Docker executor http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainerExecutor.html

Comment: I have the folder on the slave1 container, hduser:hadoop owns it, I've also saw a solution in which the folders were given ownership to yarn:hadoop, but I haven't created any yarn users. Initially the local-dirs folder was created in /tmp and had the same issue, I moved it to the hadoop folder trying to fix it. thanks for giving it a look

Comment: `yarn:hadoop` would be the case only if you deployed a [Kerberized cluster](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html).

Comment: `.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: Node hadoop-slave1:48673 reported UNHEALTHY with details ..`: you should investigate the nodemanager log on slave1, should have more details.

Comment: I've looked before.. but only at the end of the log.. While copying it in gedit to post it, I've found the error in the node manager log

Comment: I recreated the directories and now it works .. Thank you very much